# Remove anonymous JavaScript function from array/object/Set

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

How can Node's [emitter.removeListener](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener) be implemented in ES2015? Adding a callback to an array is easy:

```
let callbacks = [];
function registerCallback(handler) {
    callbacks.push(handler);
});
```

How can *that particular function* be removed later, without registerCallback returning [some identifier for the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630863/uniquely-identify-a-function-in-javascript)? In other words, `unregisterCallback(handler)` should not need any other parameter, and should remove that handler. How would `unregisterCallback` check that an anonymous function had been previously added?

Is running `handler.toString()` (and potentially a hash function on that) a reliable solution to create an identifier for the function? Or how else should `unregisterCallback` iterate through `callbacks` to remove that particular element? (Or find the appropriate key in an object or function in a Set.)

```
mySet.add(function foo() { return 'a'})
mySet.has(function foo() { return 'a'})  // false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual solution is to pass the function itself as argument to the `unregisterCallback` function. That's what's done in jQuery for example.

So the `unregisterCallback` function just has to use `indexOf` to find the index of the callback:

```
function unregisterCallback(handler) {
    var index = callbacks.indexOf(handler);
    if (~index) callbacks.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Of course it means the user code must keep the function, it can't be an function defined in the call to `registerCallback`.

This doesn't work:

```
registerCallback(function foo() { return 'a'});
// later...
unregisterCallback(function foo() { return 'a'}); // this is a different function
```

This works:

```
function foo(){
    return 'a'
}
registerCallback(foo);
// later...
unregisterCallback(foo); // it's the same function
```

You can also provide the ability to remove by name:

```
// pass either the function or its name
function unregisterCallback(handler) {
  var index = -1;
  if (typeof handler==="string") {
      for (var i=0; i<callbacks.length; i++) {
        if (callbacks[i].name===handler) {
          index = i;
          break;
        }
      }
  } else {
      index = callbacks.indexOf(handler);
  }
  if (~index) callbacks.splice(index, 1);
}
registerCallback(function foo() { return 'a'});
unregisterCallback("foo");
```

But the responsibility of name unicity is then in the user code realm, which may be OK, or not, depending on your application.

Comment: Thanks. Using the function itself as a key works with Sets too.

Comment: Interesting to note that `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` do return an identifier, rather than `clearTimeout()` and `clearInterval()` taking the same function.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Yes, it's interesting. It's probably due to the fact those functions were designed before the ["functions as first-class citizen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) nature of JavaScript was culturally obvious. JavaScript was initially very fast designed, and many initial designs can be traced to Java which is poor in that area. It might also be a case of implementation leaking.

Comment: @DanDascalescu It has been pointed to me that using the function itself in `setTimeout` and `setInterval` would make it harder to use the same function in several timers.

Comment: Hi! I know this is old, sorry, but I have to ask. How exactly does this `if (~index)` work? I never seen this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a [design](https://github.com/atom/event-kit) where the event emitter returns a callable that will update internal state:

```
const dispose = sleep.on('sheep', ::sleep.tick)
sleep.once('baanough', dispose)
```